# PostgreSQL: how to remove even rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, row-number

Structure of rows in my table is following:

```
col1   col2   col3
  a      b      c
  a      b      c
  a      b      c
  d      e      f
  d      e      f
```

I've enumerated them using row_number

```
col1   col2   col3   rn
  a      b      c     1
  a      b      c     2
  a      b      c     3
  d      e      f     1
  d      e      f     2
```

and I would like to remove every row which has even rn value.

How could I do this? My idea was with using row_number but maybe there is another solution.

Comment: are you looking for removal of duplicates from the table or just the rows with even rn values?

Comment: What you mean by "remove"? actually `DELETE` rows in table or just don't output when you do `SELECT` ?

Comment: @puzeledbysql  Actually, I mean duplicates, but if there is in example 4 the same rows, I want to leave 2

Comment: @OtoShavadze I mean DELETE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is painful because you do not have a unique value to identify each row.  You can use `ctid` on the fly to do this:

```
delete from t
   using (select t2.*, ctid as orig_ctid,
                row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by ?) as seqnum
         from t t2
        ) t2
   where t2.orig_ctid = t.ctid and
         mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;
```

Having a serial column is a much better idea, though, than relying on `ctid`.

Comment: I've got syntax error near delete t. I use PostgresSQL 9.5

Comment: @user6808217 . . . Ouch.  I used the `update` syntax not the `delete` syntax.  I don't know why they aren't the same in Postgres.